# Escape single quotes in string containing single and double quotes

Tags: php

I have a PHP string that contains single and double quotes, but am having a rough time getting it escaped properly. Even tried online quotify sites, but their result errors also.

```
$confirmation .= '<a title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fquiz%2F','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" class="">Share on Facebook</a>';
```

I don't think the double quotes need to be escaped. Still, all of my attempts result in HTTP 500 when loading the page.

How do the single quotes inside this string get escaped?

Comment: First, get [php errors to display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: You are right. Commented below - this is in fact PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To escape nested quotes in PHP, use the `\`

```
 $confirmation .= '<a title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fquiz%2F\',\'sharer\',\'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325\');" class="">Share on Facebook</a>';
```

For a complicated case with lots of quotes, it may be more readable and practical to use a heredoc:

```
$confirmation .= <<<EOT
  <a title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fquiz%2F','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" class="">Share on Facebook</a>
EOT;
```

Comment: You are correct. The code is in functions.php - I had another window open in my editor and got totally confused - twice. :S It is PHP.

Comment: YAY for heredoc  Could not agree more, for convoluted vars where lots of escaping would be needed, heredoc syntax is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`$confirmation .= '<a title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fquiz%2F\',\'sharer\',\'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325\');" class="">Share on Facebook</a>';`

Comment: Both of the answers on this post look correct to me. I tried escaping them just like your and Brandon's examples, but with no success.

Comment: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)`

Comment: Did you use 3 <'s?

Comment: Yes I did: `$confirmation .= <<<EOT ` ... I don't understand why I get an error trying to escape it manually with backslashes.

Comment: You should update your question with new sections, show what you tried and the output.

Comment: @rwkiii - you can NOT have any spaces after the `<<<EOT` on that line, it has to be purely `$confirmation.= <<<EOT`.  Also note `EOT` can be swapped with anything, but the closing has to match.  So, could be `<<<CONFIRMATION` if you wanted....

Comment: @cale_b You nailed it - I had a space at the end of the `<<<EOT` line and tabs prior to the `EOT;` line. Removing the trailing space and leading tabs resolve the error. Thanks.