# PHP variable add single quotes

Tags: php, variables, declaration

I declared a variable like this:

```
$variable = 'Hong Kong,Indonesia,India';
```

I want to add single quotes for each country. I want result like this:

```
$variable = "'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India'";
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: Escape quotes with slash. Example: `$variable = 'Hong \'Kong\',\'Indonesia\',\'India\'';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape single quotes in string containing single and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646653/escape-single-quotes-in-string-containing-single-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

You can write this way -

```
$variable = "'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India'";
echo $variable;
```

Output - 
'Hong Kong', 'Indoneisa','India'

Or you can use array rather than a single variable.

```
$country = array('Hong Kong','Indonesia','India');
echo $country[0];
```

Output -  Hong Kong

Comment: I am giving both options if he wants to separately echo each country.

Comment: Thanks for urs opinion but i want to declare single variable

Answer (score 0):

to add a single quote you have to write it like this

```
$variable = '\'Hong Kong\'';
```

Comment: Wrong example. The output will be: `\'Hong Kong,Indonesia,India\'`

Comment: No - when using double quotes you don't have to escape single quotes...so either remove the slashes or surround the string in single quotes. [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Still no - if you plan to use double quotes `$variable = "'Hong Kong'";`, if you need to use single quotes `$variable = '\'Hong Kong\'';`

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways (amongst many others) you could do this:

```
$variable1 = "'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India'";

$variable2 = '\'Hong Kong\',\'Indonesia\',\'India\'';

$variable3 = <<<HEREDOC
'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India'
HEREDOC;
```

I would say this first way is preferable, as this is the clearest. More information on these are found here: [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)