# Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, syntax-error

I have to send "id" of flight on which manager clicks approved so do to that i want php var to go in angular var somehow. I did this where the error mentioned in title occurs.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="id[index++]='<?php echo $flight['id']; ?>'">
```

Any idea about which '[' is angular compiler talking about and how to write correct expression like this? Much thanks. In angular :-

```
$scope.id=[];
$scope.index=0;
```

Okay i got a great answer which says to escape quote you can use '\' and now I am trying :-

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="id[index++]='<?php echo $flight'\['id']'; ?>'">
```

But it still isn't working and is giving this error "unexpected "[" at line: blah". Can anyone add "\" in my above mentioned line and plis make me get rid of this headache?

Comment: I'm assuming it's the `]` after `id` seeing the `'` left of `id` is closing the string. `'<?php echo $flight['`

Comment: I suspect so, but how to tackle this?

Comment: @Escape the quote. What ever the syntax is in PhP

Comment: Can you please write full <input...> syntax?

Comment: @Fran That wont work because the compiler is from angular not from PHP as the description says. Is there any way you can assign that into a variable?

Comment: Searching SO for `escape single quote in php` ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646653/escape-single-quotes-in-string-containing-single-and-double-quotes

Comment: i read that answer but can you add "\" in my <input> line and answer so that it can help me and others. I can't understand where to add '\" :/

Comment: @AsimRaja The other answer already helps others, assuming it's the fix, if it is then your question would be a possible duplicate to that question instead. Unless off course your issue is totally different. Hence, apply the changes, test it and if it fixes it, it's a possible duplicate, if not you can update your question with the code you tried that still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing your string in ng-init before it is finished.
Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="id[index++]='<?php echo $flight[`id`]; ?>'">
```